# How do I pass variables between view controllers?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

i'm having a hard time with Xcode; for some reason, it just won't let me pass a variable from one view controller class to another. It should work, i was basically just copying/pasting from my other classes (it works on all of them... except this one). I've been at it all night long, tried everything i could think of and still it remains.

Here's the view controller class where I'm making the call:

### ResultadosViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Filme.h"
#import "Festival.h"
#import "Top10Discos.h"
#import "Peca.h"

@class DetalhesViewController;

@interface ResultadosViewController : UIViewController
{
    // Navegation
    DetalhesViewController *dvc;
    BOOL isViewPushed;

    // What i'd really like to pass lol
    NSArray *array_resultados;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *array_resultados;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) BOOL isViewPushed;

@end*
```

### ResultadosViewController.m:

```
#import "ResultadosViewController.h"
#import "DetalhesViewController.h"
#import "Filme.h"
#import "Peca.h"
#import "Top10Discos.h"
#import "Festival.h"

@implementation ResultadosViewController
@synthesize isViewPushed, array_resultados;

(...)

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Navigation logic -- create and push a new view controller

    if (indexPath.row == 2)
    {
        if(dvc != nil)
            [dvc dealloc];

        NSString *ffs = [[array_resultados objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] TituloFilme];

        dvc = [[DetalhesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailedView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

        **resultadosControllerCell.array_resultados  = [self array_resultados];** 
        *"Request for member 'array_resultados' in something not a structure or union"*

        //Push the view controller to the top of the stack.
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvc animated:YES];

    }
}
```

And here's the other class i want to send the array into:

### DetalhesViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "Filme.h"
#import "Festival.h"
#import "Top10Discos.h"
#import "Peca.h"


@interface DetalhesViewController : UIViewController
{
    // Navegacao
    NSArray *array_resultados;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *array_resultados;
@end
```

I'm not sure if any of you would to see the .m file for this class; in that case, just ask.

Thanks in advance,
Hal

PS: tried with other variables (other types too), cleansed/rebuilt, recreated xib file, you name it... i'm outta tricks :(

Comment: You might get better replies if you change the title to be more descriptive. such as "Unable to pass variables between Controllers in an iPhone project"

Answer (score 4):

First off, don't use `->` — that's direct instance-variable access. It may work, but you're changing another object's instance variables without its knowledge, which is just asking for trouble.

And no, Adam Rosenfield didn't mean `dvc->array_resultados`; he meant `resultadosControllerCell->array_resultados`, which is what he said and which he based on what you said.

The correct solution is a blend of your original line and your revision of Adam's line:

```
dvc.array_resultados = [self array_resultados];
```

This goes through the property you declared in the `DetalhesViewController` class.

Speaking of which, you should declare that property as `copy`, not `retain`. Otherwise, you'll find yourself holding somebody else's mutable array, which they will then modify—more bad mojo.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't exaclty answer your question, but your memory management is a bit wonky. This line:

```
[dvc dealloc];
```

should read like this:

```
[dvc release];
dvc = nil;
```

In Cocoa, you should never call `dealloc` directly -- follow the `retain/release/autorelease` pattern and things will work better and as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but did you try using the arrow operator `->` instead of the dot operator `.` ?

```
resultadosControllerCell->array_resultados  = [self array_resultados];
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i've had it; using a cheap trick to show the info:

```
UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:ffs message:@"this gets covered" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    UILabel *myTextField = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    myTextField.text = @"FFS!";
    CGAffineTransform myTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 130.0);
    [myAlertView setTransform:myTransform];

    [myTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [myAlertView addSubview:myTextField];
    [myAlertView show];
    [myAlertView release];
```

Really hate using this, but i'm already a day late. 
I should have delivered it by yesterday.

Thanks for your help guys, if you happen to find the solution please let me know.
You never know if it'll happen again :/

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

A more competent way of doing this is to separate the data from both the viewcontrollers into a model. You will have a separate class(NSObject) called ResultadoModel.h/m. This will be a singleton, so both classes can access the same instance.

You would access the array by doing something like this(in both vcs):

```
[[[ResultadoModel sharedInstance] array_resultados] propertyOrMethod];
```

You can search how to create a singleton, it's very simple and very powerful.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these simple steps please, it should work.

In your SecondViewController:

1. Create an initializer in the second View Controller. Ex:

   -`(id)initWithResultsArray: (NSArray *) resultsArray`;
2. Create a variable for holding the array. Say `myResultsArray`.
3. Inside the `initWithResultsArray` method, save the value of `resultsArray` to `myResultsArray`.
4. Initialize the `SecondViewController` using `initWithResultsArray` instead of just `init`.
5. Present your controller as usual, you will be able to work with `myResultsArray`.

Hope this helps.

Monica ツ